# After img.on('load'), $this variable value changes and img.length differs

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to run code on multiple groups of images (grouped within `$feedthumbs`) after the page detects the first image of that group has loaded. For this example, I'm only trying to get the `.length` (count) of images per `.each` grouping.

Here's my code...

```
var $feedThumbs = $('.fi-photo-thumbs');
$feedThumbs.once().each(function(e) {

    $this = $(this);
    var firstImage = $('a:first-of-type img', $this);

    var totalImgs = $('a img', $this).length;
    console.log(totalImgs);
    // Shows correct number for each log (3, 5, 9, 3 etc)

    firstImage.on('load', function(){
        var totalImgs = $('a img', $this).length;
        console.log(totalImgs);
        // Shows incorrect number for each log (1, 1, 1, 1, etc)
    });

});
```

Why are the two `totalImgs` variable values different.

It seems as though the $this variable value changes after the `.on('load')` function. But shouldn't it stay the same as the variable was defined prior?

I've tried a variety of different ways to check to see if the images are loaded (including the [imagesloaded](https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded) js plugin), but getting the exact same incorrect result. Even tried removing `:first-of-type` in case that was the issue. Still no success.

Thanks!

Comment: Because `$this` changed. All iterations are sharing the same variable.

Comment: How can I get a variable to hold that first `this` value, so it can be used in the `.on('load')` function (without it changing)

Comment: The same way you did with `firstImage`

Comment: I need to use that original `this` value to grab different values within the `.on('load')` function. Even if I put the value from my `$this` variable into a new variable... I still can't get that original value to be used within the onload function. Sorry man, I really don't understand what I'm missing. Would you mind providing a quick example?

Comment: put a `var` in front of it.

Comment: Tried it... -> `var $this = $(this);` then `var photoThumbs = $this;` and the value still doesn't hold